# Extended control value is not setting from UI

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Hi I'm trying to extend the TextBox use that extends one in my code. in the extended control, By default, it will trim start and end.

**the code I have tried**

```
public class TextboxTrimSpaceing : TextBox
    {

        private string myVar;

        new public string Text
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value.TrimEnd().TrimStart(); }//Control is not coming here
        }

    }
```

**UI**

```
 <local:TextboxTrimSpaceing x:Name="TrimSpaceing" Text="   avi  aaa   "></local:TextboxTrimSpaceing>

  var i = TrimSpaceing.Text; //Getting Null
```

Here why my control is not going to the setter and why I'm getting Null result 
Note: it's displaying proper string in UI and I know I can maintain it in code. but I need like this.

Comment: Replacing a control property like this doesn't work. When the XAML parser sees `Text="   avi  aaa   "` it directly calls `SetValue(TextProperty, ...)`. See [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)

Comment: Means if I wrote a `TextProperty` then it will work?

Comment: There is one already. In general, don't use `new` properties at all, at least not with WPF controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trim the text, you could override the `OnTextChanged` method:

```
public class TextboxTrimSpacing : TextBox
{
    private bool _trim = true;
    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if(_trim)
        {
            _trim = false;
            Text = Text?.Trim();
            _trim = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It makes no sense to define a new `Text` property.

Comment: why cant I assign the text value? in XAML. I mean I'm just setting a prop right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Of course you can set the value of a propert. The dependency property wrappers are effectively bypassed when do this in XAML though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties

Comment: ` <Color x:Key="myClr" A="20"></Color>` let's say I have something like this here I'm creating an object of clr and assigning them a value to 20, likewise, why can't i assign Text prop.

Comment: @AvinashReddy: You can provided that the type has a `Text` property.

Comment: yes if I'm setting it then why can't I access it? Thats where I'm not able to link it up.

Comment: Access it where?

Comment: In C# `var i = TrimSpaceing.Text;` Like this.

Comment: @AvinashReddy You already know that. `Text=" avi aaa "` does not set your property, but instead that of the base class. Because the XAML parser directly calls SetValue. Read the documentation about dependency properties.